# Mongoose error - Doesnt update database second time

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I want to update my database . I have two separate documents and I want to update them. Now, it works one time, second time it doesnt work.

```
delsrequest: function(obj, callback) {
    console.log("object in deslrequest",obj)
    var rusername=obj.rusername;
    var susername=obj.susername;
    console.log("rusername",rusername,"susername",susername)
    var ty = {"username.requestssent":rusername}
    var isbn = obj.isbn;

    Books.find({"username":rusername},function(err,resp){

        if(err){
            console.log("there is err",err)
        }
        else{
            console.log("resp is ",resp)
            console.log("resp[0].requestssent is",resp[0].requestssent.length);
            var newrrs =[];
            console.log("start")
            for(var i =0;i<resp[0].requestssent.length;i++){
                console.log("inside for loop",i)
                console.log("resp[0].requestssent[i]",resp[0].requestssent[i])
                console.log(resp[0].requestssent[i].isbn,isbn)
                if(resp[0].requestssent[i].isbn==isbn){
                    newrrs = resp[0].requestssent.splice(i,1)
                    console.log("resp",resp)
                }

            }
            console.log("?end")
            console.log("resp before",resp)


            console.log("newrrs",newrrs)
            Books.findOneAndUpdate({"username":rusername},{"requestssent":resp[0].requestssent},function(err,resp){
                if(err){
                    console.log("x",err)
                }
                else{
                    console.log("y")

                    //callback(null,resp)
                }
            })

        }

    }).then(Books.find({"username":susername},function(err,res){

        if(err){
            console.log("there is err",err)
        }
        else{
            //requestsrecieved
            console.log("res is ",res)
            console.log("res[0].requestsrecieved is",res[0].requestsrecieved.length);
            var newrrs =[];
            var gtarr;
            console.log("start")
            for(var i =0;i<res[0].requestsrecieved.length;i++){
                console.log("inside for loop",i)
                console.log("resp[0].requestsrecieved[i]",res[0].requestsrecieved[i])
                console.log(res[0].requestsrecieved[i].isbn,isbn)
                if(res[0].requestsrecieved[i].isbn==isbn){
                    newrrs = res[0].requestsrecieved.splice(i,1)
                    console.log("res",res)
                    console.log("res[0].requestsrecieved",res[0].requestsrecieved)
                    gtarr=res[0].requestsrecieved;
                }

            }
          console.log("susername",susername)
          console.log("gtarr",gtarr)
            Books.findOneAndUpdate({"username":susername},{"requestssent":gtarr},function(err,response){
                if(err){
                    console.log("x",err)
                }
                else{
                    console.log("y")
                    console.log("resp[0].requestsrecieved",response)
                    callback(null,response)
                }
            })

        }

    })
    )


},
```

The first Books.find and findOneandUpdate works perfectly. The second one doesnt update.When it reaches here, it shows correct gtarr value. One value is removed which  I want to remove. I also update it. But, it just doesnt update it.

```
   console.log("susername",susername)
          console.log("gtarr",gtarr)
            Books.findOneAndUpdate({"username":susername},   {"requestssent":gtarr},function(err,response){ if(err){
```

I see nothing removed from mongodb database. I have tried looking at everything, I fail to understand its same code. One time it works, second time it doesnt. Ii also thought, may be ite because of Async thats why it is after .then . can someone please help me out.

Comment: Do you need the first find query?

Comment: yes @israel.zinc  , I have separate document for separate username. So, I use find first and remove it from person who requested this book's document and  then, i use find again to delete it from person who received this book request. So, I need two find queries.